# What is this symbol and how can I avoid it?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, symbols

Sample page:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25582316/2675672

Whenever I select the answer text, I see pipe (`|`) symbols beside my selection. See picture:

[image: what is this]

But the dev tools show that the original text does not have these symbols. In fact, these symbols only appear when I select the text. This only happens to me in Google Chrome and not IE or Firefox. I am using Windows 7 32-bit OS.

So, my question: **What is this pipe symbol doing here, and how can I avoid it?**

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a selection rendering glitch. I can reproduce the same behavior using version `37.0.2062.102` with no extensions. If you look closely, you'll also see the symbol at the beginning of every empty line.

Comment: @and31415 This is interesting! I thought it was a feature or what. Anyway, is there a way a bug report for this can be filed with Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes, through the [Chromium bug tracker](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) (a Google account is required). Chrome also includes a [built-in feedback form](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en).

Comment: @and31415 Done. The issue is reported. Thanks! I wonder if I should close this question now ?

Comment: Well, you can't close questions directly, but I suggest you leave it open anyway. Maybe someone might come up with a workaround, or you might be able to confirm whether a newer version eventually fixed the issue.